# Convert PDF into images and display them on an horizontal screen

Tags: java, html, image-processing

I have to implement a java module that takes in input a normal A4-format PDF file, creates as many images as the pages of the PDF and makes possible to display the pictures on web page on a 10 inches screen with horizontal orientation.

I found this great java library, Ghost4J for converting PDF file into a set of images.

The problem is the screen size. I have certain constraint on the container I can use inside the web page. The container has at most 500px as height and 1280px as width because we have to use a Samsung Screen DB10E-T which is touch-enabled BUT you cannot use any common gesture for, for example, zooming or scrolling. I tried to add a scrollbar to the container with a simple `overflow: auto;` but it is not even shown on the screen.

After the processing of the PDF file with Ghost4J I kept the images as they are (means that I kept the orientation and the size of the pages), but there is a big loss of quality of the image in the moment I display it on the web page.

What do you suggest me?

Comment: Add scrollbar to the container.

Comment: I forgot to say that the web app is shown on a Samsung Screen DB10E-T which is touch-enabled BUT you cannot use any common gesture for, for example, zooming or scrolling. I tried to add a scrollbar to the container with a simple `overflow: auto;` but it is not even shown on the screen. I edited the question so it can be taken into account also this feature of the screen.